# Drupal 7: adding html (image) to view's exposed filters fields

Tags: 7, views

im having a little trouble theming the output of a view's exposed filter.

I have a `node reference` field, and in the exposed filter i want to show it as a checkbox list with, instead of the title of the referenced node, the image (that is a field, obvious).

Im doing the same thing for the node_edit form:

```
    // This function is called via #process fapi key
function _mytheme_theme_pittogrammi(&$element)
{
    $lang = isset($element['it']) ? 'it' : 'und';

    foreach($element[$lang]['#options'] AS $nid => $label)
    {
        $pittogramma = node_load($nid);
        $image_field = _dwork_field_get_value($pittogramma->field_image);

        $image = '<img class="bubbleUp" src="'
                . image_style_url('pittogrammi', $image_field[0]['uri']) . '" alt="'
                . $pittogramma->title .'" title="' . $pittogramma->title .'" />';

        $element[$lang]['#options'][$nid] = $image;


        $element[$lang][$nid] = array(
            '#label' => $image
        );
    }
    return $element;
}
```

and it works perfeclty; For the `view_exposed_form` i hat to make a little change in the function (becose the lang is not present), but is almost the same:

```
function _mymodule_theme_pittogrammi_view_form(&$element)
{
    foreach($element['#options'] AS $nid => $label)
    {
        $pittogramma = node_load($nid);
        $image_field = _dwork_field_get_value($pittogramma->field_image);

        $image = '<img class="bubbleUp" src="'
                . image_style_url('pittogrammi', $image_field[0]['uri']) . '" alt="'
                . $pittogramma->title .'" title="' . $pittogramma->title .'" />';

        $element['#options'][$nid] = $image;


        $element[$nid] = array(
            '#label' => $image
        );
    }
    return $element;
}
```

And this `works` somehow, but the problem is that the image HTML looks like is passed throught `htmlspecialchars()` or something like, and rendered as text.

Im wondering why and why only on view's exposed form...

How can i change this behavior?

Comment: typically `#label` and `#title` values for FAPI elements are passed through drupals xss_filter() function. I assume Views is being more strict -- because it's so widely used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: I am using BEF module (Better Exposed Filters) that, in row 532 of `better_exposed_filters.theme` used to check_plain even the label.

Commenting that line do the trick, knowing that youre raping someone'else module (but this is the only way i found since there is no an option to dont check_plain the label)